# Redis Desktop Manager for Windows can't display UTF-8 characters as key name

Tags: windows, redis

I am using Redis Desktop Manager for Windows 0.8.8.384, I've created UTF-8 key like "北京:beijing:123", the key displays fine by itself, but folder name is not, see attached image.

[wrong display of key folder name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsbWQ.jpg)

Comment: In addition to create the keys using RDM's UI, I also tried using Python's redis client to set the keys, same problem. the keys are set with UTF-8 byte sequences, so it's really the RDM itself can't process them as UTF-8

Comment: Confirmed from redis output that the key was saved correctly in UTF-8, so it's definitely a problem with RDM not using UTF-8 to decode.